# Can you prove that $\log \prod_{k\geq 2} \frac{k-\mu(k)}{k+\mu(k)}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, mobius-function

Since for $|z|<1$ $$\log\frac{1+z}{1-z}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1},$$
and $ |\frac{\mu(k)}{k} |<1$, for $k\geq 2$ where $\mu(k)\in \left\{ -1,0,1\right\} $ is **Mobius function** then I don't know if this exercise is in the literature
$$\log \prod_{k\geq 2} \frac{k-\mu(k)}{k+\mu(k)}=-2 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)k^{2n+1}}  .$$
Here $0< \frac{k-\mu(k)}{k+\mu(k)}<1$ for $k\geq 1$.

> **Question.** Can you prove that $\log \prod_{k\geq 2} \frac{k-\mu(k)}{k+\mu(k)}$ converges?
>     **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If someone want add also the answer for: Can you show if $\log \prod_{k\geq 2} (\frac{k-\mu(k)}{k+\mu(k)})^{1/k}$ converges, in the answer of the post or in a comment I apreciate it. My computations for the first question is about 2.2..., and the scond about 0.84...

Comment: The comment of Jean-Claude is due an update in my post, since my genuine question had not mathematical sense.

Comment: $\frac{k-\mu(k)}{k+\mu(k)} = \frac{1-\mu(k)/k}{1+\mu(k)/k} = 1-2\mu(k)/k+\mathcal{O}(1/k^2)$, and $\sum_k \frac{\mu(k)}{k}$ converges (by the PNT)

Comment: Very thanks much! Now I've that think about your computations @user1952009

Comment: Then are rights the following computations $$\log \prod_{k\geq 2} \frac{k-\mu(k)}{k+\mu(k)}= \sum_{k\geq 2}\log(1-\frac{\mu(k)}{k})=\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}+O \left(  \sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k^2}\right) $$
and thus there is convergence? My goal, is then edit an answer for mysef question @user1952009

Comment: $\log \left(\prod_k 1 - \frac{2 \mu(k)}{k} + \mathcal{O}(k^{-2}) \right) = \sum_k \log (1 - \frac{2 \mu(k)}{k} + \mathcal{O}(k^{-2})) = \sum_k  - \frac{2 \mu(k)}{k}  + \mathcal{O}(k^{-2}) = \mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: now,  your job is proving that each $\mathcal{O}(k^{-2})$ is uniformly bounded for every $k$ (so that its true $\sum_k \mathcal{O}(k^{-2}) = \mathcal{O}(1)$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)=2\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
 $$ we have $$S=\log\left(\prod_{n\geq2}\frac{n-\mu\left(n\right)}{n+\mu\left(n\right)}\right)=\sum_{n\geq2}\log\left(\frac{1-\mu\left(n\right)/n}{1+\mu\left(n\right)/n}\right)=-2\sum_{n\geq2}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\mu^{2k+1}\left(n\right)}{n^{2k+1}\left(2k+1\right)}$$ $$=-2\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\mu\left(n\right)}{n}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{n^{2k}\left(2k+1\right)}.$$ The last sum is easy to calculate, using the geometric series $$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{n^{2k}\left(2k+1\right)}=\frac{n}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)$$ and so $$S=-\sum_{n\geq2}\mu\left(n\right)\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right).
 $$ Now recalling that an equivalent form of PNT is $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\mu\left(n\right)}{n}=0\tag{1}
 $$ we have, using Abel's summation, that $$S=-\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\mu\left(n\right)}{n}n\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)=2+\int_{2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{2\leq n\leq t}\frac{\mu\left(n\right)}{n}\right)\left(t\log\left(1+\frac{2}{t-1}\right)\right)^{'}dt
 $$ and so from $(1)$ we have $$S\sim2-\int_{2}^{\infty}\left(t\log\left(1+\frac{2}{t-1}\right)\right)^{'}dt=2\log\left(3\right)
 $$ and so the series converges and $2\log\left(3\right)$ is an approximation of that sum.

Comment: Is very nice @MarcoCantarini, very thanks much.

Comment: Your answer **Marco Cantarini** $$\log \prod_{k\geq 2} \frac{k-\mu(k)}{k+\mu(k)}=2\log 3.$$

Comment: Currently I don't know if your calculation was a exact value or a very good approximation, it is can you explain me why $\sim$ is not a exact identiy $=$? I've referenced this statement in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885500/on-the-convergence-of-different-infinite-products-related-with-the-m%C3%B6bius-and-me  Thanks and apologizes

Comment: @user243301 It is an approximation since I used $$\sum_{2\leq n\leq t}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\approx1.$$

Comment: Then very thanks much, and one more time my apologizes since I remember that I've spammed to you in previous comments saying that your answer was an identity $=2\log 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Thus the full answer from the user in comments is that yes, $$\log \left(\prod_k 1 - \frac{2 \mu(k)}{k} + \mathcal{O}(k^{-2}) \right) = \sum_k \log \left(1 - \frac{2 \mu(k)}{k} + \mathcal{O}(k^{-2})\right)$$
and   $$\sum_k \log (1 - \frac{2 \mu(k)}{k} + \mathcal{O}(k^{-2})= \sum_k  - \frac{2 \mu(k)}{k}  + \mathcal{O}(k^{-2})= \mathcal{O}(1)$$
since $\log(1-x)= x+O(x^2) $ when $x\to 0$, and the last identity by **Prime Number Theorem.**

Comment: I [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness) that I've to find a constant that is larger than the absolute value of any term of the sequence $k^{-2}$, and it is $1$, thus $O(k^{-2})$ is **uniformly bounded** for every $k$ and $\sum_k \mathcal{O}(k^{-2}) = \mathcal{O}(1)$. Is is right @user1952009? I have no idea, I know the definition of big oh, but don't more computations. Very thanks much for your very nice answer, too.